# Is it better to have a single, more general stored procedure or multiple stored procedures?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-design

Is it considered good practice to have a single stored procedure that has multiple nullable input parameters or different stored procedures for each seperate case?

For example, I am storing data within a general `Vehicle` table. It has several generic columns such as `VehicleName`, `Weight`, `Color` etc.... It also has a `VehicleType` column which would specify whether the vehicle was a car, plane, boat, bike etc... Each different vehicle type has its own unique properties/columns in its own table. So there would be a `Car` table with fields such as `MilesPerGallon` or `MaxNumberOfPassengers`.

Example `Vehicle` table:

```
      CREATE TABLE Vehicle
      (
          VehicleID INT PRIMARY KEY,
          VehicleType varchar(50),
          Name varchar(150),
          Color varchar(50),
          Weight varchar(50)
      )
```

Example `Car` table:

```
      CREATE TABLE Car
      (
          VehicleID int FOREIGN KEY,
          MilesPerGallon varchar(50),
          MaxNumberOfPassengers int
      )
```

When inserting data into the database, all the general fields are stored within the main `Vehicle` table while all the specific fields are stored in the appropriate table based on the `VehicleType` column value. So a `Car` value would be stored within the `Car` table.

When using a stored procedure to insert the data, would it be best to have one stored procedure that could handle all the different vehicle types or have multiple stored procedures to deal with each different vehicle type? If using just one stored procedure, I could have all the possible input parameters that are `NULL` by default.

What would be considered best practice in this situation?

Comment: A single, more general stored procedure would be a better choice

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Even with numerous null input parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most systems which use a database, the part of the system which limits performance most is the database. By this I mean that, when profiling a part of the code which does not involve stopping and waiting for user input if a database call is in the code profiled it will generally be the part of code which takes the longest.

(This is not always true, but in most commercial apps it is. If your app involves taking some simple data from a DB and then doing very compute-intensive operations - such as solving partial differential equations based on values from the DB - then it won't be true. However, most apps I have profiled - including the one I'm currently working on - DB operations can take 30% to 95% or more of the run-time.)

Anything you can do to make your DB operations more efficient is worth while. What DBs are good at is Set operations. If your stored procedures have a load of logic apart from stuff in SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE/iNSERT statements then they almost certainly aren't as efficient as they could be.

For this reason I would suggest a number of focussed efficient Stored Procedures rather than one general purpose complicated one. However, as with all performance advice, the only proof is trying things and measuring performance.